# ng-repeat limit make issue for remove

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have 1 ng-click that add md-datepicker :

```
<md-button ng-click="addItem()" type="button" >Add Infants</md-button>
```

then ng-repeat is set to 4 :

```
ng-repeat="d in radioData | limitTo: 4 "
ng-value="d.value"
ng-class="{'md-align-top-left': $index==1}"
```

everything is working as expected but I have 1 ng-click for remove:

```
<md-button ng-click="removeItem()" type="button">Remove Infants</md-button>
```

then problem start if click more than 4 time on addItem() its not show but for remove its start to remove extra first its some kind of wierd. look like its there but not show .
I read about track by `$index` but not working .
My controller is:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
  $scope.radioData.push({});
};
$scope.removeItem = function() {
  $scope.radioData.pop();
};
```

Any Idea will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `addItem()`, you push a new struct to the `radioData`.  However, you're **limiting the shown data to four items via `limitTo:4` through your `ng-repeat`**.  This means you can still add more than four items to the `radioData` array, they just won't be shown with the `ng-repeat`.  Thus, when you remove elements after adding more than four items to the `radioData` array, you still have more than four items in your `radioData` array.

You can fix this by limiting the number of items allowed to exist in the `radioData` array, as follows:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
  if ($scope.radioData.length < 4) { //Check there is space for the new struct
    $scope.radioData.push({});
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its save my day @Matt

Comment: Glad I can help @JohnDoe !  Please accept my answer if it solved your issue.